# How can I authenticate to DocumentAI in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I created a service account with the roles: Document AI Administrator and Service Account Key Admin.

However, when I try to fetch an access token using googleauth (1.7.0) Ruby gem, i get the following error:

```
Signet::AuthorizationError (Authorization failed.  Server message:)
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT Signature."}
```

Here's my code that I'm running locally on my command line:

```
scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'

authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
  json_key_io: File.open('path_to_private_key_file_of_service_account.json'),
  scope: scope)

authorizer.fetch_access_token!
```

I can get this to work when I have a user that has "ALL" permissions granted, so I know it's a permissions issue, but I don't know which roles/permissions are needed to request the access token. ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the service account as [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials) for your local development environment, then the client library should pick it up automatically.

Also according to the [Document AI Ruby Client Library Documentation - Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/docs/reference/google-cloud-document_ai/latest/AUTHENTICATION#configuration) you can use the following code to initialize a Document AI client for ruby using a credentials.json file:

```rb
require "google/cloud/document_ai"

client = Google::Cloud::DocumentAI.document_processor_service do |config|
  config.credentials = "path/to/keyfile.json"
end
```

or for all Document AI clients

```rb
require "google/cloud/document_ai"

Google::Cloud::DocumentAI.configure do |config|
  config.credentials = "path/to/keyfile.json"
end

client = Google::Cloud::DocumentAI.document_processor_service
```